# There is a way to use expo with WSL?

Tags: react-native, expo, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2

I want create a react native app using expo, but i found some problemns to iniciate.

Run `expo start` on WSL2 doesnt work. Running this creates a server based on the WSL IP address, which doesn't work;

When use the flag `--tunnel` to tunneling on WSL, expo still doesn't work;

There is a way to use expo with WSL?

I tried:

Using the wi-fi IP address instead using WSL IP, but nothing happened;

Search about on Expo and React Native official docs, I didn't find anything relevant

Comment: Can you provide more detail, such as 1) what error message are you seeing, 2) what platform are you running npm start for, 3) what version of expo are you running, 4) what WSL image are you running. We need more context to know where to help you